# how to swap Image in jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick, image, swap

How can I swap an image's SRC attribute, on click of that image?

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="./layout/images/search.png" />
</a>

$('img[src="./layout/images/search.png"]').click(function () {
    $(this).attr('src',"./layout/images/search_select.png")
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```
$("img").click(function(){
   $(this).attr("src","new.gif");
})
```

As David Hedlund points out this will change all images on a page due to the `img` selector. You could target an image using a class as sam152 suggests or, you could target an image using it's `src` attribute -

```
 $("img[src='old.gif']").click(function (){
   $(this).attr("src","new.gif");
})
```

See my demo - [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W7mq6/)

Comment: We might be able to presume the user is acquainted with sizzle selectors. Otherwise it might be worth pointing out that this snippet will change *any* image on the page to `new.gif` when clicked.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out David, I've updated the answer with a bit more info.

Comment: @user1065056 - What are you not getting?

Comment: @user1065056 - Could you post the code/mark-up in your question that you're having problems with?

Comment: @user1065056 I've set up a fiddle using your code and it does appear to work - http://jsfiddle.net/LBShe/

Comment: @user1065056 - What do you mean by permanent? The swap will only last until the page is reloaded from the server.

Comment: @user1065056 - Excellent, I'd really appreciate it if you could accept the answer if it has helped. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

If you have an image with a class called 'swap', you can use the following snippet. It uses the click event, and then attr, to change the images src attribute.

```
$('.swap').click(function(){ 
    $(this).attr('src','new/path/to/img.jpg');
});
```

Comment: i did the same, but not getting