# Swap image and button back and forth

Tags: javascript, image, swap

I need your help. Found this code on the forum, which I'd like to use:

```
<a id="element1" onClick="javascript:changeText(1)">Read More...</a>

function changeText(idElement) {
 var element = document.getElementById('element' + idElement);
  if (idElement === 1 || idElement === 2) {
     if (element.innerHTML === 'Read More...') element.innerHTML = 'Close';
        else {
            element.innerHTML = 'Read More...';
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to not only swap the text by clicking on it, but at the same time swap 2 images?

```
Situation 1: Read More... and image 1 shown
Situation 2: Close and image 2 shown
Situation 3: Read More... and image 1 shown
```

Comment: Removed Java tag, Java and Javascript are two differents things. -- Anyway, yes you need: the <img> tag where this image should be added.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Give it a try. It will be probably easier with `JQuery` than just in pure JS.  [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277524/how-to-swap-image-in-jquery) might help a bit.

Comment: Well I don't really know how to connect these two things. I can swap the text and the image but not at the same time...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).